# Why only the first click increases the vote counter but others do not?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

The php part of the code:

```
 //the JS part
 echo "<script>
  function increasevotes(e,location,user,date,vote)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent=this.responseText;
            }
        };
    xmlhttp.open(\"GET\", \"vote.php?location=\" + location + \"&user=\"+ user +\"&date=\"+date+\"&vote=\"+vote, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  </script>"
//the HTML part
echo "<span class=\"right nolikes\">{$rows['vote']}</span>
<a href=\"\" onclick=\"increasevotes(event,'{$rows['title']}','{$rows['username']}','{$rows['date']}','{$rows['vote']}')\">
<img src=\"img/like.png\" class=\"right\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\"/>
</a>"
```

The php which is used in the AJAX call. (vote.php)

```
<?php
    include("configure.php");
    $location = $_REQUEST["location"];
    $username = $_REQUEST["user"];
    $date = $_REQUEST["date"];
    $vote=$_REQUEST["vote"]+1;
    $query="UPDATE journals SET vote={$vote} WHERE title='".$location."' AND username='".$username."' AND date='".$date."'";
    $qresult=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    echo $vote;
?>
```

**Problem:**

Initially, the database contains vote as zero. So, a like image and 0 is displayed. When I click on the like image, the vote is increased 1 both in the database and also updated in the html page. But, clicking on the like symbol again does not increase the vote count to two. Why?

Comment: Are you sure votes update on `the html page` also when you click first time?

Comment: Yes. The like image is displayed and 1 is shown. In the database too, it becomes 1. Clicking the second time does not alter votes anywhere

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) (`location='%3BDROP%20TABLE%20journals%3B--`)

Comment: Btw, It's also considered as bad practice to echo that amount of JavaScript codes and HTML codes by PHP, I'm not sure about your situation, but there is always away to prevent doing that.

Comment: I basically need to show a different HTML page to people who've logged and who haven't. So I use if else statements to echo the corresponding parts. Suggest an alternative method

Comment: I would suggest to create different HTML files and place some [value place holders] and then with PHP based on the condition, you can use `file_get_contents('html_file')` and replace those place holders with php variables.  the JS codes can also be included as an external file or you can add them inside the HTML files. again this is one of the way came in my mind. if you need more info, let me know .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will implement.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is in your JS callback you are updating only the text of

```
<span class="right nolikes">{$rows['vote']}</span>
```

with this line :

```
e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent=this.responseText;
```

But you also need to update the amount of vote on the onclick part :

```
<a href="" onclick="increasevotes(event,'{$rows['title']}','{$rows['username']}','{$rows['date']}','{$rows['vote']}')"> 
here it still uses old vote number
```

I would suggest you do it in SQL and PHP part instead of passing current amount of vote to PHP. 
so instead of `$vote=$_REQUEST["vote"]+1;` in your php part do this :

```
$query="UPDATE journals SET vote=vote+1 WHERE title='".$location."' AND username='".$username."' AND date='".$date."'";
```

and then to update the value you can either do it quickly or wait until call back but change it to this :

```
var oldVote = parseInt(e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent); 
e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent= oldVote++;
```

There are also more way to fix this but I think this might help you.

Comment: Well I used to make this mistake as well :D

Comment: put vote count in one input field.. And increase every time on click... Use that input value as vote value.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! It's working. But I don't get this part "But you also need to update the amount of vote on the onclick part :" I'm anyways increasing the vote when I click first in the database. So $rows['vote''] in the onclick part should've changed right?

Comment: It updates the DB thats true but as you don't refresh the page your PHP code which is generating your JS and HTML codes is not re-executing.  in that case the current amount of vote you are passing to onclick function is not getting updated and will always pass the old value as long as you don't refresh the page.. makes sense? :) you can also double check it with observing your request contents in network window of your browser.